# 2nd level view in ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an address "http://localhost:3579/MusicStore/StoreManager" which is really showing "http://localhost:3579/MusicStore/StoreManager/Index".

I want to go to another another address on the same level from the index: "http://localhost:3579/MusicStore/StoreManager/Edit". Edit is a view inside the StoreManager folder, so a 2nd level view.

I'm confused as to which controller I'd even put the method in. I tried putting my "public ActionResult Edit" in MusicStoreController, but it wasn't recognized. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your action is in the right place, but you will need to make sure there is a route specified to route your URL to that action.  Make sure a route like this is specified in your global.asax or area registration file if your project is using areas:

```
context.MapRoute(
                "MusicStore_Edit",
                "MusicStore/StoreManager/{action}",
                new { action = "Index"}
            );
```

Comment: Good answer. But now it can't find the index view. It's looking inside "~/Views/StoreManager/Index.cshtml". This is because I specified "StoreManager" as the default controller. But, I want it to look for the view inside "MusicStore/StoreManager"

Comment: @Andrew - You can specify the path to the correct location of the Index file in the Index action. In the `return View()` part of the method specify the correct path like `return View("~/Areas/Admin/Views/MusicStore/StoreManager/Index.cshtml")`

Comment: I was hoping for a less manual way. Nonetheless, this works. Thank you.

Comment: @Andrew - If your file is in the `ViewLocationFormats' then it will automatically find it without having to specify the path. Check this out for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976235/custom-viewengine-asp-net-mvc-3